# C application falling over on strcat

Tags: c, strcat

My application falls over when I make the following call to strcat any ideas why?

```
char *encryptedLine[255] = {0};  
char encryptedLString[8];        
sprintf(encryptedLString, "%08lX", L);
strcat(*encryptedLine, encryptedLString);
```

Comment: do you understand what char *encryptedLine[255] construction is? And what is L, that you use in sprintf?

Comment: `*encryptedLine[255]` - what are you trying to do?

Comment: What's with all the down votes? I clearly gave enough information for the question to be answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*encryptedLine` is NULL pointer: it needs to point a `char` buffer.

`*encyptedLine` is equivalent to `encryptedLine[0]`, which is the first entry in the array of `char*` `encryptedLine`:

```
char *encryptedLine[255] = { 0 };
```

which is a NULL pointer.

To fix, either change to:

```
char encryptedLine[255] = { 0 };

strcat(encryptedLine, encryptedString);
```

or:

```
encryptedLine[0] = malloc(255);
strcat(*encryptedLine, encryptedString);
```

I think you also need to increase the size of `encryptedLString` by 1 as:

```
sprintf(encryptedLString, "%08lX", L);
```

will attempt to write 9 characters: 8 specified by the format plus 1 for the null terminator:

```
char encryptedLString[9];
```

Comment: So do you mean I should remove the = {0}? That doesn't seem to work

Comment: Most likely you want to remove *

Answer (score 1):

encryptedLine is an array of 255 pointers initialized to NULL.  *encryptedLine is a NULL pointer.  You are passing a NULL pointer as the first argument to strcat, so it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `strcat()` with 0 as first parameter. `*encryptedLine` is `encryptedLine[0]` and you assigned `{0}` to it

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of `char` *pointers*

```
char *encryptedLine[255]
```

You haven't allocated any memory and assigned it to any of them. Crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* LINE 1*/ char *encryptedLine[255] = {0};  
char encryptedLString[8];        
sprintf(encryptedLString, "%08lX", L);
strcat(*encryptedLine, encryptedLString);
```

Look at LINE1, it allocates an array of 255 pointers to char that are all initialised to 0, then you do a strcat, which will try to write the value from encryptedLString into the location pointed to by the pointer *encryptedLine which is NULL, which isn't allowed.

Just allocate some memory for encryptedLine's pointers, and this program won't crash.